# Why HttpContext.Current.Session is changing evertime I visit the same page ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

Here's the scenario

I have a page lets say login.aspx having a button called login, on click event of that button when I check for the SessionID its shows a specific value for example "A"

Now I am making a call to some external page and that page then calls this page again.

for instance once I click login button I call a twitter app and when user authorizes it, I am redirected back to the same page, but now when I am accessing the SessionID its a new ID.

I have no idea why this is happening, I just want to have the same SessionID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have multiple web servers, do you?

If so, and if you're not using a shared session state provider, you'd tend to see this kind of behaviour.

Edit.

OK, next question...

Is the URL that the Twitter authorisation is returning to using exactly the same domain name?

For example, if your application is running on http://127.0.0.1:1234/ and the return URL is http://localhost:1234/ ?

Edit2: Yes?

When you are redirected back from the Twitter app on 127.0.0.1, the ASP.NET session cookie isn't being passed back to the web server because the domain is different.

You need the domain that the app is running under to match the Twitter callback URL.

Reconfigure the Twitter callback URL to localhost:1234 and I think you should be OK.

Comment: No I am running this on my dev machine, with the default server that comes with Visual Studio IDE

Comment: The Dev machine is running on http://localhost:1234 and Twitter Callback URL is http://127.0.0.1:1234

Comment: Since Twitter do not accept localhost as valid input for the url. Is there any workaround so that I can test the same in the dev env. before actually checking it in production/live env

Comment: Do it the other way. Have the app run up on 127.0.0.1:1234

Answer (score 2):

Are you adding any data to the session? You need to do so for the session ID to "stick".

Comment: Yep. If you don't store anything in the session, you get a new id every time. +1