# Session.SessionID changes on every page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, session-state

I'm running a .NET 4 website. Locally, it runs perfectly, but something very strange is happening on the live server. On every single page, the `Session.SessionID` changes - the problem this is having is that I store the users shopping basket in the database using Session.SessionID as a key - when they move to the check out the basket is empty of course.

I have seen suggestions to put `Session["dummy"] = 1` in the `Session_Start()` method of Global.asax, but this hasn't helped.

What can i do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I gave an answer to this same issue a while ago.

You can find the details [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685154/why-httpcontext-current-session-is-changing-evertime-i-visit-the-same-page-asp-ne/6685205#comment-7909059)

Comment: Hi Steve - how so? Im not running on any different domains...im just one running one website on one server

Comment: Fair enough; I didn't say it was the right answer ;-) It's usually a cookie issue. Can you add a cookie to HttpResponse & check for it from HttpRequest, just as a quick test?